# Align text and input so that they are neatly inline vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

A bit of a beginner's question, I am trying to make my form to look like the following image where the text on the left are vertically aligned and the input field has the same widths.

[twitter form](http://www.multyshades.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Twitter-Sign-up-Page-using-HTML5-And-CSS3-no-js.jpg)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="d-inline">Full Name: </label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" formControlName="firstName">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h6>Some text</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="d-inline">Email: </label>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" formControlName="email">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h6>Some text</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which gives me the following result. I also want the input to stretch to the remaining parent container so that it stops before the "some text".

[my attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xT4kc.jpg)

I have tried to set the width css property of the input field to 100% hoping that it will do it. However, that just stretch it all the way which forces it to go to the next line.

I am using bootstrap 4 with Angular2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give your p tag a min-width. I gave the input a max-width so it's better when your screen size is smaller. Hope this answers your question

```
p.d-inline {
    min-width: 75px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;  
    margin-left: 30px;
}

h6 {
    margin-left: 30px;  
}
input {
    max-width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you are using Bootstrap.
Why not Use Bootstrap Form then?
You can find how-to [HERE](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal)

**Open the following snippet in Full Page to see how it works**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">




<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-2">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-3">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As `form-horizontal` is not working as expected in bootstrap 4  so, you can try like this.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group row">
            <label class="d-inline control-label col-md-3 text-right">Full Name: </label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="First Name" formControlName="firstName">
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h6>Some text</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group row">
            <label class="d-inline control-label col-md-3 text-right">Email: </label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email" formControlName="email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h6>Some text</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```